# In virtualization, should Windows host Linux or should Linux host Windows?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I bought a new home server which I'm going to use for developement, HTPC and many others. I'm thinking of havine one Windows VM and multiple linux VMs.

I've thinking about this for last few days but I don't have any conclusive answer.

What do you prefer, and give me some reasons too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Oh wait, you wanted a real answer.

The truth is that it doesn't matter terribly, provided both OSes support the bare metal equally well. Linux can be a bit more efficient in some things, but in the end it's mostly taste since you'll probably be dealing with the host OS most frequently.